# Efficient way to add a new field based on values in a different field in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create a new field based on an existing field. Basically, if a row in the existing field contains a string starting with #, use the value in that row for the row in the new field. If it doesn't, use the most recent value in the existing field (with #) for that row in the new field.

Sorry if it sounds confusing, here's an illustration:

```
df = data.frame(V1 = c("#text1", 1, 3, 4, "#text2", 2, 4, 3, "#text3"), 
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df_desired = data.frame(V1 = c("#text1", 1, 3, 4, "#text2", 2, 4, 3, "#text3"), 
                        newcol = c("#text1", "#text1", "#text1", "#text1", "#text2", "#text2", "#text2", "#text2", "#text3"), 
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Here's what I attempted but it's returning an error:

```
df_new = df %>% mutate(newcol = ifelse(grep("#", df$V1[]) == 1, df$V1[],lag(df$V1[])))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can copy `V1` in `newcol` if `"#"` is present in it or copy `NA` and then fill those missing values with `tidyr::fill`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(newcol = ifelse(grepl("#", V1), V1, NA))  %>%
  tidyr::fill(newcol)

#      V1 newcol
#1 #text1 #text1
#2      1 #text1
#3      3 #text1
#4      4 #text1
#5 #text2 #text2
#6      2 #text2
#7      4 #text2
#8      3 #text2
#9 #text3 #text3
```